# Create object of a class containing anonymous inner class via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, inner-classes, actionlistener

I'm trying to create an object of class **Test** containing anonymous inner class - **ActionListener** - via reflection.

The class is loaded properly. I can list any fields, methods, contructors etc. The problem is, when I'm trying to create object with constructor containing ActionListeners for some buttons. Everything works fine, when listeners are commented out.

When I'm using Constructor.newInstance() method, I'm getting:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at Engine.createObj(Engine.java:78)
    at Main$3.actionPerformed(Main.java:107)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class Test.Test$2 from class Test.Test
    at Test.Test.<init>(Test.java:123)
    ... 42 more
```

Test.java:123 is where the listener is implemented of course. Test.Test$2 is anonymous inner class file.

Loading class code which looks like working fine:

```
    public void loadClass(File file) {
    reflectClass = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fis.available()];
        int read = fis.read(bytes);
        fis.close();
        if (read != bytes.length) {
            return;
        }
        reflectClass = defineClass(null, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        resolveClass(reflectClass);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And object creation:

```
public void createObj(Constructor ct) {
    Class[] types = ct.getParameterTypes();
    //... some params generating code, not important, i'm using non-param constructor.
    try {
        object = ct.newInstance(oParams); // Here is the problem.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's have another go...

So this is an `IllegalAccessError`, not to be confused with `IllegalAccessException` (extends `ReflectiveOperationException` in Java SE 7). This is about messing up the classes, rather than reflection.

It looks as if you have loaded one of the classes using a "custom" class loader, and the other via a normal class laoder. Even if package names match, classes loaded from different class loaders are in different packages (from an early update of J2SE 1.2, IIRC). One class tries to access (link to) the other relying upon "package private" access, but the JVM denies it because the packages are actually different.

Comment: Documentation for ClassLoader's default constructor which I invoke says "Creates a new class loader using the ClassLoader returned by the method **getSystemClassLoader()** as the parent class loader." So shouldn't it use the "normal" class loader at last? Anyway I was trying to use the system classloader, but couldn't find any way to load class from file.

Comment: @dragoste The system class loader will be the parent, but it's still a different class loader.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
    public void loadClass(File file) {
    reflectClass = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fis.available()];
        int read = fis.read(bytes);
        fis.close();
        if (read != bytes.length) {
            return;
        }
        reflectClass = defineClass(null, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        resolveClass(reflectClass);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code will not work reliably; carefully reading the JavaDoc of FileInputStream.available and FileInputStream.read should reveal why.

It may be that mutilated class file data contributes to that exception.

Comment: In reality it'll probably work for files under a certain size, and then mysteriously fail. An API call to read a file into a byte array might be a good idea.